# Facebook Like Button problems

Tags: html, facebook

I've attached a Facebook like button to a friends parents home page for there business but the problem is that on when someone likes the link, on the Facebook page it shows a different logo attached to the message on Facebook (a Austrian flag instead of an Australian). The code for the like button is

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=17923769214223454&amp;xfbml=1">    
</script>
<fb:like href="http://www.velumount.com.au/en/" send="false" layout="button_count" width="450" show_faces="true" font="">
</fb:like>
```

And the website I've placed it on - 
http://www.velumount.com.au/en/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've to set the metatag og:image, i.e. placing in your head something like

```
<head>
     <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.velumount.com.au/config/logo-en.gif" /> 
</head>
```

by the way, you can always check how your link will look like with [Facebook URL linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/)